# (Apache server) linking to the root directory when it is different from the web domain

Tags: html, .htaccess

This is really basic, but I could not find the answer, be it by Google-fu or experimentation.

My personal webpage at my university's website is controlled in the following manner: I have write access in the `/home/myname` folder on the server, and the contents of `/home/myname/WWW` can be read from the internet at the URL `www.myuniversity.org/~myname`, delivered by an Apache server. While I have no access to the global configuration of the server, we can use .htaccess files quite widely.

The default root domain being `www.myuniversity.org`, the usual "fetch the CSS" instruction would be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~myname/mystyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

I do not like that, because should I ever move to another host, I would have to go back in all files and rewrite the `~myname/` part. (The same question applies to a lot of internal links `<a href=...>`.)

What I am looking for would be a sort of "semi-relative path", where I tell once for all that the root is `www.myuniversity.org/~myname/` rather than `www.myuniversity.org` and all paths start from there.

I thought I had found the solution by adding the following line in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /~myname/
```

Then the "portable" CSS inclusion by

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

works, but only in the root folder; `www.myuniversity.org/~myname/foo.html` will find the CSS but `www.myuniversity.org/~myname/sub/fol/ders/bar.html` will not.

I am probably mistaken with what the RewriteBase is supposed to do, but I would assume it just prepends its argument to any call from the internal pages.

What is the solution (if any exists) to have a portable set of files with "semi-relative" paths (i.e. paths given as absolute paths from a given root, but the root can be set at a single point and need not match with the domain root)?

I have read [Website css and javascript are not accessible within their respective folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543882/website-css-and-javascript-are-not-accessible-within-their-respective-folders) which has similar symptoms but the root cause is different, as well as [Using htaccess rewrite to make a subdirectory be its own root for root relative path requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982205/using-htaccess-rewrite-to-make-a-subdirectory-be-its-own-root-for-root-relative) which I did not fully understand.